# Control does not switch while new window pops up

Tags: java, selenium, testing, testng

This is regarding selenium automation testing based in java, While trying to select a language from a window that pops up after i make a click on the current window, the control however does not transfer from the current window to the popped up window.

[image: POP up]

How do i enter values on the new pop up tab and then go back to the original one.

Answer (score 0):

That's a new window, For that you'd have to switch the focus of web driver :

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
// write the code here for click on Page 1
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

**//Do your things on Page2**

**//Switching Back to Page 1**

```
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
driver().switchTo().defaultContent()
```

Comment: after these statements i have my code where it is finding the element on the web page, but it cannot find the element.

Comment: i see now there are frames within the page. I am unable to switch frames and find the element.

Comment: Share the relevant HTML

Comment: you can switch frames by index: driver.switchTo().frame(frame_index); or by id or name...  driver.switchTo().frame("id/name");